# server not receiving json request from react page

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have my form like this Home.jsx

```
function Home(){
    var [name,setName] = React.useState("")
    var [email,setEmail]=React.useState("")
    var [password,setPassword] = React.useState("")

    function handleChange(e){
        var field = e.target.name
        var value = e.target.value
        if(field==="name")
        setName(value)
        else if(field==="username")
        setEmail(value)
        else
        setPassword(value)
    }
function signup(e){
    fetch("/",{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
            name:name,
            username:email,
            password:password
        })
    })
e.preventDefault()

}
return(<div><form onSubmit={signup}>
    <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name" value={name} placeholder="Name"/>
    <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="username" value={email} placeholder="Email Address" required/><br/>
    <input onChange={handleChange} type="password" name="password" value={password} placeholder="Password" required/><br/>
    <button className="rounded btn-lg" type="submit" name="button">Sign Up!</button>
</form>
</div>)
}
```

i have my server like this

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"build")))
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
}
)
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
})
app.listen(3000)
```

when i try to print the req.body then it is printing undefined. i have checked in the chrome dev tools, the req payload is correct. but my server is not able to receive the req.body.
what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you use body parser to pass your request in the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prinitng req to see what you are receiving?

Also have you tried the npm body-parser to ensure that the express server can read the data request?

Comment: i have tried printing the req, it is printed as {}. also, used body-parser.

Comment: Did you use body parser?
 const bodyParse = require('body-parser'),
app.use(bodyParse.json({extended: true}));

Comment: i did not update the post, problem got solved. thanks though.